# Search & delete temp files/folder (script's got a failure)

Tags: batch-file, search, delete-file, temp

I use this script to clean history, cookies and cache (Temporary Internet Files) for all users AND it should also clean the temp dir BUT there seems to be something wrong.

Two things get mixed up I think, the `%temp%` variable (= D:\TEMP in my environment)
AND the users temp dir in the `%userprofile%`.

```
:: Works on Win XP  -and-  on Win 7

@echo off

Set "RegKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
set "regkey2=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\shell folders"

call:getspecialfolders "Cache, History, Cookies"

For /f "tokens=*" %%? in (
 'Reg.exe QUERY "%RegKey%" ^|findstr /ric:"\S-1-5-21-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$"'
 ) do (
 For /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in (
 'Reg.exe QUERY "%%?" /v ProfileImagePath ^|find /i "ProfileImagePath"'
 ) do call:Go %%B
)

start ""/w "%windir%\system32\RunDll32.exe" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

:end ***


goto:EOF
:Go
   call Set "Target=%*"
   If EXIST "%Target%" call:Clear "%Target%"
exit /b 0

:Clear
REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$Cache%
   pushD "%~1\%$$Cache%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_TEMP_IE.txt

REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$History%\History.IE5
REM    pushD "%~1\%$$History%\History.IE5" &&(
REM    rmdir /S /Q .
REM    popD)2>C:\test1_History_IE.txt

REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$History%
   pushD "%~1\%$$History%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_History.txt

REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$Cookies%
   pushD "%~1\%$$Cookies%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Cookies.txt

ECHO.&echo.%~1\%$$temp%
   pushD "%~1\%$$temp%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.txt
exit /b 0

:getspecialfolders
   Set "FoldersToClear=%~1"

   For %%* in (%FoldersToClear%) Do (
     For /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in (
     'reg.exe query "%regkey2%" /v %%* ^|find /i "%%~*"'
     ) do Call:sf1 "%%~B" "%%~*"
   )
   Call:sf2 "%temp%" "temp" "%userprofile%"
exit /b 0

:sf1
   Call set "sf=%~1"
   Call set "$$%~2=%%sf:%userprofile%\=%%"
exit /b 0

:sf2
   Call set "sf=%~1"
   call Set "usr=%~dpns3"
   Call set "$$%~2=%%sf:%usr%\=%%"
exit /b 0
```

BUT somehow I can't get the last "temp part" to function so it cleans the %temp% (D:\Temp in my environment) and to also find al "temp dir's" in the %userprofile%.

**ie.** this for instance does work for %temp%**:**

```
PushD "%Temp%" && (
ATTRIB -S -H -R -A /D /S & (
For /f "Tokens=*" %%* in ('dir "%Temp%" /B') Do (
RD "%Temp%\%%*" /S /Q || Del /F /S /Q "%Temp%\%%*"))&PopD)2>c:\test0b_TEMP.txt
```

**and this ie.** work for the "user(s) temp"**:**

```
::Set Search directory to "Documents and Settings" folder
(Set Target=%AllUsersProfile:~0,-10%)

title,Finding the Temp subfolders in %Target%&COLOR 9E

If EXIST "%Target%",(
  For /f "Tokens=*" %%* in ('dir "%Target%" /B') Do (
   cd/D "%target%\%%*\Local Settings\Temp" && (
   ATTRIB -S -H -R -A /D /S >nul & (
  For /f "Tokens=*" %%* in ('dir /B') Do (
   RD "%%*" /S /Q ||Del /F "%%*" )))>nul)
 )
```

I hope some one can help me out fixing the script, I think it's in the :sf2 and/or in combination with the %temp% part, somehow 2 things get mixed-up now ("users temp" en "environment temp").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, this time I think there *is* a way to fix this, namely, by adding a check whether the variable contains a relative or an absolute path, directly before proceeding with the cleanup. The idea is to test for the presence of the colon (`:`) in the string. If the colon is present then the path could not be converted to a relative path previously and so should be used as is, without pre-pending the profile path, otherwise the profile path should be attached before going on.

Here's a basic example that you can test and play with, if you like:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET somepath=D:\TEMP
CALL :checkpath
SET "somepath=Local Settings\Temp"
CALL :checkpath
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF

:checkpath
IF "%somepath%"=="%somepath:*:=%" (ECHO Relative path) ELSE ECHO (Absolute path)
```

In your particular situation I would probably apply the method like this:

instead of

```
…
ECHO.&echo.%~1\%$$temp%
   pushD "%~1\%$$temp%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.txt
…
```

I would try

```
…
IF "%$$temp%"=="%$$temp:*:=%" (SET "tmppath=%~1\%$$temp%") ELSE SET "tmppath=%$$temp%"
ECHO.&echo.%tmppath%
   pushD "%tmppath%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.txt
…
```

As you can see, a temporary variable is used to store the actual path to be processed. I understand it is enough to replace only the part where the temporary folder is being cleared, but you can see that the method can be easily applied to other folders as well, if needed.

Comment: Andriy M, the HERO of the (my) day ;-p

Comment: **(it does give an "error"/message when directories are empty, why is that?)**

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are talking about. If you mean the error when executing `rmdir /S /Q .`, then it occurs not only on empty directories, but every time (on Win 7 at least). `rmdir` attempts to remove the current directory (`.`) as well as all its contents and complains about being unable to do so (remove the current directory), which is fair enough, because the system prohibits deleting the active (current) folder.

Comment: That wasn't 'my' error. What I received was to the effect of 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' (sorry, I'm not sure if that is the exact English equivalent, the original was in Russian). So, hm... odd indeed.

Comment: it just seems odd to me that the "error" returned is: _,,The system can not find the path specified''_. Probably because it tries to remove the current directory like you just mentioned indeed. The script does delete the files/dir's in the specified directory (unless file is in use), so that part seems to be working fine. Is there a way to suppress the above "error"/message perhaps?

Comment: yes, when I read the "log files" created by the script I see some error's because of files that are in use by the system, these "error"/messages do get surpressed, the above "error"/message still get sent to screen (as you can see here, url: http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9127/errorif.jpg)

Comment: Errors are typically output to the so called *standard error* device, as opposed to *standard output* which is used for 'normal' output. Standard output can be suppressed by `>NUL`, while standard error by `2>NUL`.

Comment: **of course**, i'll give _>nul_ a try instead of _2>>C:\an_error_file_name.txt_ and see if everything is suppressed than

Comment: The `cannot find the path` error could be caused by some of the PUSHD commands, if there's an attempt to switch to a non-existent directory. It's a good thing then that there's `&&` that links `PUSHD` with the following block and doesn't let it execute when `PUSHD` fails.

Comment: weird thing is that all directories DO exist.

Comment: changing _2>_ into _>nul_ makes things worse, now a get a whole lot of ,,file in use'' errors **:'(** I'd like to keep all output suppressed somehow

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `sf2` subroutine is trying to get a relative path of the Temp folder by cutting off the beginning of the path, which is essentially the user profile path:

```
Call set "$$%~2=%%sf:%usr%\=%%"
```

where `sf` contains the Temp folder and `usr` the user profile. So instead of, for instance, `C:\Documents and Settings\APOC\Local Settings\Temp` you would get simply `Local Settings\Temp`.

But there's a problem. Though the `sf` variable is assigned with the proper path, the `usr` variable, on the other hand, for some reason is assigned with the *short named variant* of the user profile path. That is, instead of something like `C:\Documents and Settings\APOC` it receives something like `C:\DOCUME~1\APOC`. Here's the offending line:

```
call Set "usr=%~dpns3"
```

So, when the formerly quoted line is executed, the expected substitution never happens, because `C:\Documents and Settings\APOC` doesn't match `C:\DOCUME~1\APOC`, naturally. As a result, the `$$temp` variable ends up with the complete path instead of the relative path, and because of that, the relevant parts of your code that reference `$$temp` don't do their job as expected.

In short, I think you don't need that `sf2` routine at all. The `sf1` routine seems to do just the same as `sf2`, only with a different set of parameters to pass. So, instead of

```
Call:sf2 "%temp%" "temp" "%userprofile%"
```

I'd suggest you to try this:

```
Call:sf1 "%temp%" "temp"
```

Comment: this is what I got/get with "my" script (nothing changed yet):                                                                      
**C:\Documents and Settings\admin-lksvdd\D:\TEMP**

Comment: I see, I didn't account for the 'non-standard' `D:\TEMP` path... Tell me, please, what is the purpose of this chain of actions: first get the path of a special folder, then cut off the beginning part (the one that matches the profile path), only to return later to full path again by attaching the profile path to where it was initially? At first I thought that relative paths were obtained only once, then all profile paths were applied to them by turns. If that is not so, i.e. if the script always cleans up *only* the current user's special folders, I think you should just omit that extra stage.

Comment: Not sure, it's an old script I "borrowed" out of a google cache (the script owner/builder doesn't react) so I tried it here.   It does indeed also clean **multiple users** though, see the query used on ProfileImagePath, this line spots/finds all "active"-users.    _Call:sf2 "%temp%" "temp" "%userprofile%"_ for CurrentUser (only? as far as I know)     AND _"ProfileImagePath" QUERY_ to find "active"-users.

Comment: Default windows temp used and it does work again: _%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Temp_ (for currentuser) **and** _%SystemRoot%\Temp_ (system variable). Now how to fix the script so it will still work when none windows defaults are used...That's when things go horribly wrong :-(

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line for temp a little, is this a correct way? (it does work but is it properly formated?)

```
IF "%$$temp%"=="%$$temp:*:=%" (SET "tmppath=%~1\%$$temp%") ELSE SET "tmppath=%$$temp%"
ECHO.&echo.%tmppath%
   pushD "%tmppath%" &&(
   ATTRIB -S -H -R -A /D /S & (
   rmdir /S /Q . || Del /F /S /Q .
   )&popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.txt
```

+Extra "Del /f /s /q" for possible hard/read-only files (and additional attrib)

**By the way** 
There still seems something not going 100% in the script with the "temp"-part, I changed my default temp settings in windows to the default paths voor testing purposes and I get these 3 error's:
[screenshot of the error](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9127/errorif.jpg) | url: http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9127/errorif.jpg

script run with the windows default temp-path's:

[user] %UserProfile%\Local Settings\Temp ***and*** [system] %SystemRoot%\Temp

I'm not sure why I get these error's, when I set both temp parameters to D:\TEMP, I get 3 times the same sort of error but than for D:\TEMP instead of available/active users \local settings\Temp. Perhaps the problem is in locals~1???
(The temp-directories do get cleaned though, but why does it say it can't find the path?)

Comment: Problem does **NOT** occur when the directories are full with files, so the above error's only occur when the directories are empty.  How come / Why?  Can this be prevented or else hide these messages? (that there wasn't anything found)